# Ubuntu Server - Apache2 - Files show as raw data

Tags: server, apache2, pdf

0

Ubuntu server running Apache2 and then I try to display a PDF or PNG file it shows the raw file, not the graphical view. Using different browsers do not open the file in normal viewing mode, but shows the raw data.

Example: https://docs/mydoc.pdf Result: %PDF-1.7 %���� 1 0 obj <> endobj 2 0 obj <> endobj 3 0 obj <> endobj 4 0 obj <> strea

Same file on another server opens as you'd expect.

Different browsers same results. Checked mime.types for pdf entry.

Comment: Look into HTTP headers served with your file, probably it is served as `text/plain` instead of `application/pdf`.

Comment: Thank you - yes it appears to be text/html - second question is how/where do I fix that?

Comment: There are multiple sources Apache uses. First, check `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` directory for `mime.conf` and `mime.load` entries to verify if MIME module is correctly loaded. If `mime_magic` entries are also there, remove them for now. Then, check your `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file and ALL the files it includes (from `conf.d` and `sites-enabled` subdirectories) for any lines mentioning MIME type for PDF file. Finally, check also `.htaccess` file in the same directory where PDF file is located. In any of these places something could be modified.

Comment: Basically, you should familiarize yourself with Apache configuration (the documentation at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/ is pretty extensive) before trying to debug any problems.

Comment: Thank you - I believe I've checked those files and they appear correct - found this is for more than PDF's also PNG, JPG etc. Appears to be any mime type file. Have another server that works fine so I enab;ed\disable the same mods and still not working. No .htaccess in the mix.

Comment: Apparently this was the issue in the apache2.conf file:

SetHandler application/x-httpd-php

Comment: If you used the `SetHandler` directive unconditionally, then yes, because it caused ALL files to be treated as PHP files, so effectively, HTML code.
This directive must be used conditionally, only for files with `.php` extension. If you installed PHP, then the file `php.conf` (may include some number after `php`, corresponding to PHP version) in subdirectory `mods-enabled` usually already contains the correct configuration.